# How to disable storing data in index while pd.read_csv in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am reading a txt file which looks like:

```
        Time    Node    AppId   SeqNo   Name     Type   HopCount
         0      5         0       0    abc/p1/    abc     1
         0.8    5         12      0    abc/p1/    abc     0
```

The values in txt file are tab separated.

I have used the following code to read txt file and store in data frame:

```
df1=pd.read_csv(pathname,delimiter='\t')
```

The output dataframe stores the value of time as index which shouldn't happen.

The dataframe looks like:

[Dataframe Ouput(click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtYew.png)

The results should look like:

```
       Time   Node  AppId   SeqNo   Name     Type   HopCount
         0      5     0       0    abc/p1/    abc     1
         0.8    5         12      0    abc/p1/    abc     0
```

Comment: Check your text file for extra tabs and trying adding `index_col=None`

Comment: @Xnkr default is `None` you need to pass `False`. https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv